# Does the "startup object" option in Visual studio have a limit of numbers?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am learning C# as it's used in a project. In Java I know I can have more than one class containing main entry and run any of them at my choice, either from command line or a IDE - this is good for testing.

And I found something similar(more or less) in Visual studio - that's the setting in project properties -> application -> startup object, in which I can pick up from its dropdown any class that contains "public static void Main(String[] args)".

It worked fine for my first 5 testing classes, however after I created my 6th class I couldn't see it from the dropdown list in Startup object.

Is it a bug or a glitch or it's set so that there is a number limits there? I am using Visual Studio 2015 and below is my code snippet (from MSDN site)

```
class SimpleIteratorTester
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> EvenNumbers(int FirstNumber, int LastNumber) {
        for (int i = FirstNumber; i <= LastNumber; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                yield return i;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        foreach (int num in EvenNumbers(1,20)) {
            Console.WriteLine(num.ToString());
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really an answer, but in Visual Studio you can create a test project. In a test method in a test project you can press cltr+r+t (run test) to run and debug the single test method the cursor is in. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh598957.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Agreed with Roy.  Take a look into creating a Unit Test project, in your solution.

Comment: Another suggestion...  less advanced...  if your tests are simply running the same thing with different parameters, simply change the Command Line Arguments.  Found under project properties, Debug tab.

Comment: thanks to all. I might just go create a test project as suggested - I got used to unit testing in java too. Just curious about why the startup object didn't work as supposed, provided I didn't make mistakes on my end.